# Ignorar un campo de una Entidad para diferentes end-points con JPA

Tags: java, rest, jpa, spring-data, annotation

Tengo 2 llamadas en mi clase `controller`:

- GET /list
- GET /list/{id}

Y tengo una `Entidad` con varios atributos, pero uno de ellos tiene un tamaño demasiado grande, en este caso, el atributo 'information'.

```
@Entity(name = "entidad")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Entidad {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private byte[] information;
```

Para dar mas agilidad a los end-points, lo que pretendo realizar, es que al llamar al primer end-point, me devuelva un listado de todas las `Entidades` pero con el atributo 'information' a null.

Y cuando realice una llamada al segundo end-point (/list/{id}), me traiga este atributo relleno.

Me gustaría poder hacerlo directamente con las llamadas a base de datos, para no tener que recuperar el dato en el primer end-point y setearlo a null desde mi código.

He estado viendo que la anotacion de `@Transient`, me permite hacer esto, ignorar el campo, el problema es que se ignora siempre, tanto en /list como en /list/{id}, ya que se usa sobre la misma `entidad`.

¿Es posible poder utilizar la anotacion de @`Transient` solamente para el primer end-point, e ignorarla en el segundo end-point?

Comment: ya intentaste agregando constructores a tu entidad y con jpql un `select new miObjeto(m.nombre(),m.apellido()) from MiObjeto m`?